# Detecting the user pressing F10 in WPF

Tags: wpf, keyboard-events

My WPF application has behaviour triggered by the functions keys (<kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd>).

My code is along these lines:

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Key)
    {
        case Key.F1:
        ...
        case Key.F2:
        ...
    }
}
```

This works for all F-keys except <kbd>F10</kbd>. Debugging, I find that `e.Key == Key.System` when the user presses <kbd>F10</kbd>.

In the enum definition, `F10 = 99` and `System = 156`, so I can rule out it being a duplicate enum value (like `PageDown = Next = 20`).

So, how do I tell when the user presses <kbd>F10</kbd>?

Is it safe to check for `Key.System` instead? This feels a little dirty - might it be possible that `Key.System` would ever result from some other key being pressed? Or is there some setting somewhere that will make <kbd>F10</kbd> report as `Key.F10`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In addition to Yacoder's response, use the following to check for the <kbd>F10</kbd> key:

```
case Key.System:
  if (e.SystemKey == Key.F10)
  {
    // logic...
  }
```

The [SystemKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyeventargs.systemkey.aspx) property will tell you which System key was pressed.

Comment: That's cool. I find I also have to set `e.Handled = true` when `e.Key == Key.System`, to ensure the focus doesn't get left on the control box. (The control box is invisible in my app as I'm using `WindowStyle = None`, which makes the default F10 behaviour even more confusing for the user.) Also, `e.Key == Key.System` when the user presses the Alt key too - and maybe in some other cases - so `e.SystemKey` is definitely the way to go instead of just assuming it's F10. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

[F10 launches the window menu. It's the same in all Windows apps.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/33821c88-4246-485a-8ac7-eee921ab3864)

It seems that `Key.System` is the expected value for the F10 key.

Answer (score 1):

Answer with DataContext:

```
    public partial class BankView : UserControl
    {
        public BankView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(BankView_KeyDown);
        } 

        private void BankView_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                switch (e.Key)
                {
                    case Key.F4:
                        ((BankViewModel)DataContext).OpenAccount();
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ...
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me, for <kbd>F1</kbd>

```
Private Sub Window_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If (e.Key = Key.F1) Then
        ShowHelp()
    End If
End Sub
```