# F10 key detection in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I am programmatically generating keypressed event in WPF using this code:

```
 new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice,
        Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource,
        0, args.Key)
    {
       RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent
    }
```

where args.Key is the argument of the KeyUphandler of my WPF usercontrol.

Further I am trying to convert this WPF Key into a Win32 Virtual-Key using [KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyinterop.virtualkeyfromkey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like this:

```
var keyData = (Keys)KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(e.Key == Key.System ? e.SystemKey : e.Key);
```

This method is working fine for normal keys but it is not working for F10 key ( I am getting keydata as None for F10).
Any help would be great.

Comment: Pls check here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103497/detecting-the-user-pressing-f10-in-wpf

Comment: I have already seen that article. The problem I am facing is that I am creating the new object of KeyEventArgs and then I am unable to convert WPF key to virtual key using KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey method.

Comment: Rather than attempt to fake key presses, you are better off calling the code that would be called upon those specific key presses.