# Editing item in TreeView by ContextMenu or HotKey

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

I would like to enable editing an item in `TreeView` just in two cases:

- when a user clicks at `Edit` button in `ContextMenu` of `TreeView`
- when a user click `F2` at the selected item of TreeView.

My xaml of `TreeView`:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding FooColl}" >
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame x:Key="proxy" Value="{Binding}"/>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type treeViewModel:NodeViewModel}" 
                                                     ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="treeNode.png" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FooValue}">
                    <TextBlock.ContextMenu>                                
                      <ContextMenu>
                          <MenuItem Header="Edit"/>
                      </ContextMenu>
                     </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

My first thought was to use `TextBox` instead of `TextBlock` in `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. However, the edit mode of `TextBox` is enabled by `MouseClick`. Consequently, it is not what I want.

Any thoughts about how can I do that?

Comment: you can use IsReadOnly property? by defaut it's false and when user clicks at Edit you turn it to true

Comment: @Amine yeah, I can use `IsReadonly`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use IsReadOnly property:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding FooValue}" IsReadOnly="{Binding ImReadOnly}">
```

And to handle F2 key-press, you can try this :

```
    public partial class MyView : UserControl
    {
        public MyView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(KeyDownEvent);
        }

        private void KeyDownEvent(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                switch (e.Key)
                {
                    case Key.F2:
                        var vm = this.DataContext as YourViewModel;
                        vm.YourCommand.Execute(null);
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //...
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: look at this example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103497/detecting-the-user-pressing-f10-in-wpf

Comment: and how can I handle this in my viewModel?

Comment: you can call Command from code behind. var vm = this.DataContext as YourViewModel; vm.YourCommand.Execute(null);

Comment: please, write your comments into an answer and I'll mark it. Thanks.:)